# Sufficient set of features for distinguishing items

Tags: classification, inference

My input is a set of objects having different values with respect to a set of features (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5). The output should be a set of minimal features allowing to distinguish all these objects or if not possible, the features that distinguishes most of these objects.

[image]

Fo example, F1 distinguishes objects 4 (value of 2) and 5 (value of 11) from the rest of objects. We need to distinguish obj1, obj2 and obj3. F2 distinguishes Obj2 (value of 4) from the obj1 (value of 6) and Obj3 (value of 6). After combining both features F1 and F2, we can distinguish obj4, obj 5, obj4. I need an additional feature that allows to distinguish obj1 from obj3. F4 would do the job, since obj1 (value of 9) and obj 3 (value of 10). Our set allowing to distinguish all objects is then F1, F2, F4. Note that F6 is useless since it does not help distinguish our objects.

Is there a way to obtain this set of features that allows to distinguish all objects, knowing that I have more than 500 features and more than 500 objects.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Honestly if you only want to "distinguish" the objects you could just plot them and see which ones are different. More formally, you could probably use hierarchical clustering.

Comment: Thanks. In fact the numbers in the table above are just hash code. The distance between the values has no means. What clustering method can I use ?. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if these are just hashes without any meaning, then how would you compare them, given that distance is not meaningful?

Comment: @user2974951 yes this is my problem. The distance between the values is meaningless. I would like to know the relevant features (attributes) that help  differentiate these objects.

Comment: @bi_scholar. Yes it is an elaborated form of the other post, which has been closed.

Comment: As is right now (as you have presented it) this problem is not solvable. If the values in the table are meaningles how then can we conclude anything from them? Maybe you need to give us more context for these values / hashes and what they represent.

Comment: @user2974951. Each line (object) represents an algorithms that transforms a picture (F1..F6) into another picture. The values in the table represent the hash of the resulting picture (hash function applied to Base64 representation of the picture.

Comment: As I said, if these are hashes then they have no meaning, so comparing them is meaningless as well. But these hashes of yours are weird since they have very nice similar numbers, so maybe there is something else going on here? If I understand you correctly you are trying to find the records which have an "abnormal" value for each variable?

Comment: @user2974951. Thanks. The presented numbers are for illustration only. In fact, the numbers are hash codes  produced from pictures Base64 hex.Each column corresponds to one single picture. So each column is independent from the others.